# php string - same and yet not the same

Tags: php

Basically I have 2 strings. They are EXACTLY the same string. However, when I do `if ($a == $b)` it says they are different. I print them out, they are exactly the same I see on browser.

The string's a password, `$a` can login but `$b` cannot login. What gives? Weird!

Comment: Show us the two strings in question maybe?

Comment: Are they encoded differently?

Comment: Paste the strings. Impossible to answer without seeing data

Comment: and check the vartype (just to be sure)

Comment: do `echo bin2hex($a),"\n",bin2hex($b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if (trim($a) == trim($b))

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are some "blanks" in one of the string you don't see when printing on browser.
Printing `'>' . $a . '<'` and same for `$b` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viewing the strings in a debugger, or compare white space.